# Нужна тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в предложении "*В настройках(,) каждому договору можно присвоить индивидуальное название*"?

Comment: Без контекста эту фразу можно понять так, что есть некий постоянный набор каких-то "договоров", названия которых регулируются  настройками. В такое верится с трудом... Вероятнее, автор неудачно выразил свою мысль.

Answer (score 4):

**В настройках // каждому договору можно присвоить индивидуальное название.**

**Запятой нет**, ***в настройках*** ― это обстоятельственный детерминант, отнесенный ко всему предложению, после него делается небольшая остановка голоса, но запятой она не обозначается.

В то же время структуру предложения **желательно подкорректировать**, так как слово-детерминант можно отнести к первой падежной форме, а это не так. **Детерминант надо распространить,** чтобы он выглядел самостоятельным членом предложения, например:

**В системных настройках // каждому договору можно присвоить индивидуальное название.**

Или что-то вроде этого.

Конечно, здесь мы рассматриваем отдельное предложение, а как это выглядит в тексте ― трудно сказать. Может быть, понятно и так.